# WAMP .htaccess gives Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess

when i use .htaccess it give me Internal Server Error

```
RewriteEngin On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile2.php?u=$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile2.php?u=$
```

Comment: RewriteEngin should be RewriteEngine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they already mentioned in the comments it is spelled `Engine`, but there's also no need for two rules at this example

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ profile2.php?u=$1
```

## EDIT:

Try running this and see if the error goes away. If it does then you need to enable `mod_rewrite`, if not then it's somewhere else. Thanks to @abhikchakraborty for the suggestion.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ profile2.php?u=$1
</ifModule>
```

Comment: check the error log and see if there is something obvious !!

Comment: now it give me 
The requested URL /pets/amro_dev was not found on this server.

Comment: This means that mod_rewrite is not turned on. The block I gave you would have rewritten the url only if mod_rewrite was enabled, since it's not, apparently there's no such page and that's why you're getting url not found

Comment: yes the mod_rewrite is not turned on u need to turn on and restart the apache !!